# Include current timestamp in filename?

Tags: bash, ssh, mysqldump

I have to create a lot of DB backups manually using `mysqldump`, for example like this:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot my-db > my-db.sql
```

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to include the current date or timestamp into the filename, so that the file would look like this: `my-db-20150917.sql` (or another format is fine as well, even a timestamp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How can I datestamp my file names?

To include the current time/date in a filename, use a combination of `date`, and command substitution:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot my-db > my-db-`date +%Y%m%d`.sql
```

The [`man` page for `date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) explains the other options you can use; but in this context you might also be interested in including time:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot my-db > my-db-`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`.sql
```

### Wait, what's this 'command substitution'?

Quoting from the [bash hackers wiki on command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst):

> The command substitution expands to the output of commands. These commands are executed in a subshell, and their `stdout` data is what the substitution syntax expands to.

Basically, `date -%Y%m%d` outputs `20150917`, and we use the backtick (`` ` ``) form of command substitution to include that output in the command you supplied for backing up your database. We could equally have used:

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot my-db > my-db-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql
```

to achieve the same result.